# JodaTime will always change to 2015 if withYear set to 2016

Tags: android, jodatime

This is really driving me crazy. The code below

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime()
    .withYear(2014)
    .withWeekOfWeekyear(52)
    .withDayOfWeek(1);
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d MMM yyyy");
String firstDayOfWeek = dateTimeFormatter.print(dt);
Log.v(FILE_NAME,"display date? " + firstDayOfWeek);
dt = new DateTime()
    .withYear(2015)
    .withWeekOfWeekyear(52)
    .withDayOfWeek(1);
String lastDayOfWeek = dateTimeFormatter.print(dt);
Log.v(FILE_NAME,"display date? " + lastDayOfWeek);
dt = new DateTime()
    .withYear(2016)
    .withWeekOfWeekyear(52)
    .withDayOfWeek(1);
lastDayOfWeek = dateTimeFormatter.print(dt);
Log.v(FILE_NAME,"display date? " + lastDayOfWeek);
```

Somehow will always output:

```
display date? 22 Dec 2014
display date? 21 Dec 2015
display date? 21 Dec 2015
```

As you can see, the last display date should display 2016, not 2015. It seems that everytime I set withYear to 2016, it will magically change to 2015. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I have cleaned and rebuild my project many times but the output is the same.

Comment: perhaps try assign the string to a new string? I see you are using the lastDayOfWeek variable twice... might be the problem?

Comment: @riggaroo thanks. already did that but still the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `withYear(...)` does not do what you think because it uses the standard calendar year and not the year of week date as described in ISO-8601-paper. Please compare following two snippets. Only the second one does what you need:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime().withYear(2016).withWeekOfWeekyear(52).withDayOfWeek(1);
System.out.println("joda=" + dt); // joda=2015-12-21T18:26:12.776+01:00

DateTime dt2 =
    new DateTime().withWeekyear(2016).withWeekOfWeekyear(52).withDayOfWeek(1);
System.out.println("joda=" + dt2); // joda=2016-12-26T18:27:59.606+01:00
```

See also the [documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withWeekyear-int-). The fine difference between calendar year and weekbased year is only noticeable at the end or start of a year (like today).

**Explained in detail the behaviour:**

If choosing `new DateTime()` for today, the second of January 2017 and then setting the calendar year to 2016 results in: 2016-01-02. But this date is in week-of-year 53 belonging to week-based-year 2015. This 53rd week starts on 2015-12-28, so the expression `withWeekOfWeekyear(52)` will go back one week to 2015-12-21 (what you observe in first case).

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand your explanation, but your answer works, so thanks a lot. Anyway so what's the reason anyone would use withYear then?

Comment: @imin Sorry for not quite having understood. I try it again: A calendar year is always from first of January until 31th of December. But a week-based-year (year-of-weekdate) is described in ISO-paper as a calendar range bound to the week cycle. Its start is always on Monday and can therefore deviate from first of January, depending on if first calendar week has at least 4 days which impacts the exact position of the first calendar week (and week-based-year) relative to the calendar year.

Comment: @imin The method `withYear(...)` is usually the preferred one - as long as you operate with months and days. But if you work with week-of-year and day-of-week (week-date-view) then and only then you should work with `withWeekyear()`.